# Проблема с реализацией функционала односвязного списка C++

Tags: c++, указатели, структуры-данных, односвязный-список

Я хочу реализовать симметрическую разность двух множеств, заданных односвязным списком. Проблема заключается в том, что написанная мной функция изменяет один из операндов. Элемент множества являет собой кортеж из максимум 3-х чисел, количество чисел в кортеже - переменная varNum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct item
{
    int data[3];
    item *next;
    void print(int varNum) {
        cout << "(";
        for(int i=0;i<varNum-1;i++)
            cout << data[i] << "; ";
        cout << data[varNum-1] << ")";
    }
};

class List
{
private:
    item *head;
public:
    List();
    ~List();
    void add(int data[3]);
    void print(int varNum);
    int calc(int varNum, int point[3]);
    bool isLinear(int varNum);
    List sum(int varNum, List a);
    List mult(int varNum, List a);
};

List::List()
{
    head=NULL;
}

List::~List()
{
    while (head!=NULL)
     {
        item *temp=head->next;
        delete head;
        head=temp;
     }
}

void List::add(int data[3])
{
    item *temp=new item;
    copy(data, data+3, temp->data);
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
}



void List::print(int varNum)
{
    item *temp=head;
    if (temp==NULL) cout << 0;
    else {
        while (temp!=NULL)
        {
            temp->print(varNum);
            cout << " ";
            temp=temp->next;
        }
   }
}

int List::calc(int varNum, int point[3])
{
    item *temp=head;
    int val=0, term;
    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        term=1;
        for(int j=0;j<varNum;j++)
            if (temp->data[j]==1) term*=point[j];
        val=(val+term)%2;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return val;
}

bool List::isLinear(int varNum)
{
    item *temp=head;
    int cnt;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cnt=0;
        for(int j=0;j<varNum;j++)
        {
            if (temp->data[j]==1) cnt++;
            if (cnt>1) return false;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return true;
}

List List::sum(int varNum, List a)
{
    item *temp=head, *t;
    List sum;
    int cnt;
    bool eq=false;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        eq=false;
        t=a.head;
        while(t!=NULL)
        {
            cnt=0;
            for(int i=0;i<varNum;i++)
                if (temp->data[i]==t->data[i]) cnt++;
            if (cnt==varNum) {
                eq=true;
                break;
            }
            t=t->next;
        }
        if (!eq) sum.add(temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp=a.head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        eq=false;
        t=head;
        while(t!=NULL)
        {
            cnt=0;
            for(int i=0;i<varNum;i++)
                if (temp->data[i]==t->data[i]) cnt++;
            if (cnt==varNum) {
                eq=true;
                break;
            }
            t=t->next;
        }
        if (!eq) sum.add(temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return sum;
}

List List::mult(int varNum, List a)
{
    List mult;
    item *temp=head, *t;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        t=a.head;
        while(t!=NULL)
        {
            List term;
            int termData[3];
            for(int i=0;i<varNum;i++)
                termData[i]=max(t->data[i], temp->data[i]);
            term.add(termData);
            mult=term.sum(varNum, mult);
            t=t->next;
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return mult;
}

void getPolynoms(int &varNum, List &a, List &b)
{
    ifstream in("i.txt");
    if (!in.is_open()) {
        cout << "WRONG NAME OF FILE";
        return;
    }
    int n, m;
    in >> varNum; // кількість змінних
    in >> n;
    int temp[3];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<varNum;j++)
            in >> temp[j];
        a.add(temp);
    }
    in >> m;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<varNum;j++)
            in >> temp[j];
        b.add(temp);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int varNum;
    List a, b;
    getPolynoms(varNum, a, b);
    cout << "A at the beginning:\n";
    a.print(varNum);
    cout << "\nB at the beginning:\n";
    b.print(varNum);
    List m=a.sum(varNum, b);
    cout << "\nA after the addition:\n";
    a.print(varNum);
    cout << "\nB after the addition:\n";
    b.print(varNum);
    cout << "\nThe sum is:\n";
    m.print(varNum);
    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

```
A at the beginning:
(0; 0; 0)
B at the beginning:
(1; 1; 0)
A after the addition:
(0; 0; 0)
B after the addition:
(7232248; 7209152; 0)
The sum is:
(1; 1; 0) (0; 0; 0)
```

Меня интересует, почему изменяется b, и как это пофиксить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вызове `List List::sum(int varNum, List a)` правый операнд передаётся копированием. т.е. компилятор создаёт новый объект List, в который копирует все значения старого. Из значений там только указатель `item *head`.

На выходе из метода вызывается деструктор этого объекта, который освобождает всю память по этому указателю. Так что когда B пытается распечатать, имея уже некорректный указатель, получаются случайные значения.

По завершении программы может вылететь некий exception, связанный с повторным освобождением памяти по протухшему указателю.

**Как исправить**

Передавать объект не копированием, а по (константной) ссылке:

```
List List::sum(int varNum, const List& a)
```